# Designing the db and state mutations and requests of a form builder in react with graphQL, faunaDB, nextJS & Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, faunadb

I'm working on a next JS, React, Apollo, graphQL, faunaDB App. I am trying to architect how a form builder would work with it's mutations to fauna via graphQL. I am able to run mutations from the playground, and can query from the front end and build my form. Interaction seen here https://www.loom.com/share/7f7d1e1231d445f2be6b5db2c81239b6

Now I am pretty sure I can figure out how to run a mutation on the front end, my concern is when to run it? See I have the following code. Which queries faunaDB, and outputs form input elements from the state (which is populated by the query) (currently just ones of the type text) and allows you to add new form input types to the state causing a rerender and displaying a new form input element. This is all well and good.

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const INPUT_VALUES = gql`
  query GetInputValues {
    allFormInputVals {
      data {
        name
        _id
        type
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Home = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(INPUT_VALUES);

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormState(data?.allFormInputVals?.data);
  }, [data]);

  const addInput = () => {
    const blanktext = {
      __typename: "FormInputType",
      name: "Product Image",
      _id: uuidv4(),
      type: "text",
    };
    console.log(formState);
    setFormState([...formState, { ...blanktext }]);
  };

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="button" value="Add Form Input" onClick={addInput} />
        {formState?.map((val, idx) => {
          const nameId = `name-${idx}`;
          const typeId = `type-${idx}`;
          return (
            <div key={val._id}>
              {val.type === "text" && (
                <>
                  <label htmlFor={nameId}>{`Name #${idx + 1}`}</label>

                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name={nameId}
                    id={nameId}
                    className={val.type}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={typeId}>{`Type #${idx + 1}`}</label>

                  <select name={typeId} id={typeId} className={val.type}>
                    {data.allFormInputVals.data.map((item) => {
                      return (
                        <option key={item._id} value={item.type}>
                          {item.type}
                        </option>
                      );
                    })}
                  </select>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

However my mutation options in the playground seem to be limited to only adding one what is called a document at a time, which is one object. If I console log my state that I want to add to the db it looks as follows. Now I can do a mutation in the playground where I can add one of these objects. But I want to be able to add all of them at once. On a save operation. I want to do this because I dont want to run a request of every addition to the form, I want to use react state to handle the form until the very end and then do my db request.

```
[
   {
      "__typename":"FormInputVal",
      "name":"name",
      "_id":"291541872966369805",
      "type":"text"
   },
   {
      "__typename":"FormInputVal",
      "name":"name",
      "_id":"291541888089981453",
      "type":"text"
   },
   {
      "__typename":"FormInputVal",
      "name":"Product Image",
      "_id":"255f95e0-bff1-4e75-81fc-d6f3f9a72446",
      "type":"text"
   }
]
```

Now I have created a graphQL schema the has Users, which can have many Forms, and Forms which can have many inputs. It looks like so. The @relation directive is specifice to faunaDB. It works how I expect it to, beyond this mutation issue I have been mentioning.

```
type Form {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  user: User
  formInputVals: [FormInputVal!] @relation
}

type FormInputVal {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
  formRoot: Form!
}

type User {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  forms: [Form] @relation
}

type Query {
  allForms: [Form!]
  allUsers: [User!]
  allFormInputVals: [FormInputVal!]
}
```

See I can mutate the DB with the following. Where I select a specific form and add a input, thus causing a rerender of the frontend and the form input shows up. This is all well and great. This is an example muation of that type.

```
mutation{
  createFormInputVal(data:
    {formRoot:{connect:"291541554941657608"},name:"name",type:"text",index:0}){
    name
    type
    index
    formRoot{
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But here is where the root of the problem lies.

I want to take that state created by react and add it to a faunaDB collection which is called `formInputVal` the graphql schema is mapped to the db collections.

I talked to Fauna support and they mentioned a @resolver directive where I can run a DB function and add multiple documents(objects) at once so far the lambda function syntax for faunaDB is above my understanding. They mentioned this article for the function https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/ecommerce#function and this one for the resolver https://forums.fauna.com/t/placing-an-index-on-a-field-in-an-embedded-type/778/4

Let's clarify,

Am I approaching this right? I am open to changing the schema. What would you do if you wanted to solve this problem with alternative approches or the same approach, but with a missing piece I don't understand.

Why can't I just pass an array of objects to the mutation for the correct formID, and it add's that many document's to the collection in one query. Is there any sort of general pratice for creating a generative form like this.

Ok thanks any help ahead of time.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following mutation but it does not work. It haults with the following error `Unknown argument 'formInputVal' on field 'createFormInputVal' of type 'Mutation'`

```
const ADD_INPUT_VALUES = gql`
  mutation AddInputValues($formInputVal: FormInputValInput!) {
    createFormInputVal(formInputVal: $formInputVal) {
      name
    }
  }
`;

const [createFormInputVal, { data: createInputData }] = useMutation(
    ADD_INPUT_VALUES
  );

...
<form
        onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const res = await createFormInputVal({
            variables: formState,
          }).catch(console.error);
          console.log(res);
        }}
      >
...
```

Comment: you've never heard of input types, right? https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Comment: No I haven't heard of these, looks like it might be what I am looking for, will have to look at some more examples to see how I would use them, thanks.

Comment: I'm still a little stuck on how I would write the mutation using the input type, faunaDB says the input types are autogenerated and used in the mutations but not sure how I would pass a object to it. Any ideas https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/input

Comment: I see this input type in my docs `FormInputValInput` in the playground but not sure how to use it in a mutation?

Comment: not read anything ... but looking at type defs probably you should use `createForm`, not `createFormInputVal`

Comment: hmm still not sure how that would help. That would be creating a new form, when I want to create new inputs for a given formId

Comment: I'm pretty sure you [generally] wanted to create a form in one step ...  show generated input types for both mutations

Comment: well I would like to create a form yes, but as a next step I am going to need to create inputs for already created forms, so I premade the form as a mutation in the playground. and created some inputs, that are references to the form, they sit in a different collection. My idea was you would select a form and render out it's inputs, and you would be able to add inputs to them via a mutation, so I wouldn't want to at this point be generating a new formId it is already there. Currently I am querying all the inputs of any form, but later I will select them by form. Kinda confusing.

Comment: test **all** your scenarios on playground ... you probably can [1] create a form from scrach (using state array of inputs) in one step using creteForm mutation (with passed array of inputValues) ... but you want to [2] edit some existing form (and existing [DB stored] inputs) ... in this case you have to use `createFormInputVal` mutation on each 'add' (and add to state in `onCompleted`) and use some `updateForm` to save changes in form ... (edited inputVals needs mutations, too - use subcomponents), (edit forms from 'form template' requires own copies of inputVals at start, to not share edits)

Comment: your saying I have to create a mutation (or a call to the database) every time a new input value is added. That seems execsive, there must be a better way to approach this.

Comment: it depends ... on create not (make an order with many order lines in one step) ... on edit/update probably (like edit/change single todo) ... test use cases on playground, code later, you have 4 mutations (create+update input, create+update form), check and test possible args

Comment: That is pretty much where I am stuck, I can't figure out how to write these mutations, the main reason I posted this question in teh first place.

Comment: you wrote mutations are already generated .. use playground with some data/query variables

Comment: all the options are for doing one document at a time, this is where I am stuck, I can't figure it out in the playground, nothing populates for trying to do multiple documents at a time. I'm starting to think it's not possible

Comment: should I not just pass an object into one of the fields in the document. So one document has a field with all it's inputs, but I don't know how to even do that. Oh well, thanks for the help thus far

Comment: For now I have just decided to do one db call per addition, I don't see another way at this point in time

Answer (score 0):

If the root of the issue here is mutating or creating multiple documents at once, I think it got duplicated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68930202/534056

A couple of things to watch out for:

- Choose a name for your custom inputs that does not equal `[type name] + Input`.  This is what Fauna uses for the auto-generated CRUD operations, and if you define one yourself the it will override the generated one. For example, given the type `Form`, Fauna will generate an input type called `FormInput`, so don't use that for a custom one.
- If you want to pass an array of data as input, specify the argument as a List type (placed in square brackets).
- If you are updating some documents, you will need to pass in the ID. The GraphQL API hides some details around Refs, so in your UDF, you will need to reconstruct the ref from an ID.