# Fauna DB GraphQL mutation updating many formInputs of a form via their ID's

Tags: javascript, graphql, faunadb

I have the following graphQL schema, running on faunaDB

```
type Form {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  user: User
  formInputVals: [FormInputVal!] @relation
}

type FormInputVal {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
  formRoot: Form!
}

type User {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  forms: [Form] @relation
}

type Query {
  allForms: [Form!]
  allUsers: [User!]
  allFormInputVals: [FormInputVal!]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would query and write a mutation where i would update a specific form id and update all the specificed documents related to that form via there id's or what are called references in fauna db.

I can update the form name with this mutation

```
mutation{
  updateForm(id:"291541554941657608",data:{name:"test"}){
    name
  }
}
```

but beyond that I can't seem to figure out how to update multiple FormInputVals of the type Form. I talked to faunaDB, and they said I might need a resolver throught there lambda function that allows me to do so, any one familiar with this at all. I have posted another question, but I have changed my end goal in this one, but this question is similar [Designing the db and state mutations and requests of a form builder in react with graphQL, faunaDB, nextJS & Apollo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391911/designing-the-db-and-state-mutations-and-requests-of-a-form-builder-in-react-wit)

See I have a object from my form that maps to the documents ID's in the collection in fauna DB. It looks like so.

```
[{"291705061039407629":{"name":"test","type":"text"}},{"291705951034016264":{"name":"test","type":"text"}}]
```

How would I upate say two matching records in faunaDB for the FormInputVal type. The numbers represent the ID of the document in the collection.

Here's a screenshot of the GraphQL docs for updating a formInputVal, my issue is I want to update multiple documents at once.

[image]

and here is the updateForm docs

[image]

Update: I have figured out that create option can add multiple documents at a time, just have to figure out if I can update or replace all of them. This is what worked for adding multiple documents at once.

```
 mutation{
  updateForm(id:"291541554941657608",data:{
    name:"hello",
    index:0,
    formInputVals:{
      create:[
        {name:"test", index:0, type:"text"},
        {name:"test", index:0, type:"text"},
        {name:"test", index:0, type:"text"},
      ]
    }
  }){
    name
    formInputVals{
      data{
        name
        type
        index
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show `updateForm` input types, not `updateFormInputVal` ... or both

Comment: ok added them as well

Comment: ... and you can see that ... **you can't simply replace/update form array elements/inputVals** ... you can update single, existing inputVal (queried from form) by id (using `updateFormInputVal` mutation) ... `updateForm` mutation, on the other hand, allows to create new inputVals (entire data sets) or connect/disconnect inputVals to/from form by array of ids ... try in playground these possibilities, adapt react/UI code later

Comment: ok well than I am stuck, becasue I don't want to update existing single input val, I want to update multiple and if I use updateForm your saying I can create entire new dataSets, but I want to replace existing ones. And connecting disconnecting just changes the relatioship. None of these accomplish what I need. What would you do to  save the state of all these newly added form inputs in the DB via graphQL, I dont see how this is accomplished. I have been in the playground all day and every combination leaves me at dead ends.

Comment: hmmm, test if `create` option can update entries ... https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/graphql/relations#add-todos

Comment: so were defintely getting closer, I'd ideally like to replace all the documents in a create, i  see no way to update them though with the create option. But definetely this is an improvement. I updated with my code above

Comment: try to update, just add an existing id within inputVals.create params

Comment: I get a `"Field 'id' is not defined by type 'FormInputValInput'`

Comment: type, of course ... then no update possibility using create

Comment: do I have to do the resolver custom lambda route than?