# Trying to understand FQL for faunadb lambda function hit by mutation with resolver in graphQL playground

Tags: javascript, graphql, faunadb

I have the following graphQL schema. The part I am troubled with is the Mutation, it has a resolver that points to a faunaDB lambda function which I want to take ideally an array of inputs and update a faunDB collection documents by there ID's.

However I can't even get password understanding how to pass data from the mutation to the lambda and return a message or anything back at all beyond an empty array.

Below my schema is the faunaDB FQL lambda function I have written, it's pretty basic at this point.

I guess what I am wondering is what exactly is passed to the faunaDB lambda function and what can I do with it. Can I pass an array of objects to it, and update via FQL the DB documents associeted by ID.

Any help on this would be great, just getting to this point has been a ride. I am more than happy to provide any more details as needed.

Thanks!

```
type Form {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  user: User
  formInputVals: [FormInputVal!] @relation
}

type FormInputVal {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
  formRoot: Form!
}

type User {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  forms: [Form] @relation
}

type Query {
  allForms: [Form!]
  allUsers: [User!]
  allFormInputVals: [FormInputVal!]
}

input FormInputValInput {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
}

type Mutation {
  updateMultipleInputVals(input: FormInputValInput): Form!
    @resolver(name: "multiple_inputs")
}
```

faunaDB function

```
Query(Lambda(["input"], []))
```

Update: I have tried the following, but it says I need to return an array, I am returning an object, not sure how to fix that.

```
Query(
  Lambda(["input"], Get(Ref(Collection("FormInputVal"), "291705061039407629")))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array as input to a UDF, including if that UDF is used as a GraphQL resolver.

A couple of things to watch out for:

- You named your input to the custom resolver the same thing that Fauna
  would auto-generate for the `FormInputVal` type, which effectively
  overrides it.  Choose a name for your custom inputs that does not
  equal `[type name] + Input`
- If you want to pass an array of data as input, specify the argument
  as a List type (placed in square brackets).
- Make sure the return type matches the output of the UDF.  In your
  examples, the schema specifies `Form`, but you are returning a
  `FormInputVal`
- If you are updating some documents, you will need to pass in the ID.
  The GraphQL API hides some details around Refs, so in your UDF, you
  will need to reconstruct the ref from an ID.

Here is an updated schema:

```
type Form {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  user: User
  formInputVals: [FormInputVal!] @relation
}

type FormInputVal {
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
  formRoot: Form!
}

type User {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  forms: [Form] @relation
}

type Query {
  allForms: [Form!]
  allUsers: [User!]
  allFormInputVals: [FormInputVal!]
}

input FormInputValMultiUpdateInput {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  index: Int!
  type: String!
}

type Mutation {
  updateMultipleInputVals(data: [FormInputValMultiUpdateInput]!): [FormInputVal]!
    @resolver(name: "multiple_inputs")
}
```

And a UDF

```js
CreateFunction({
  name: "multiple_inputs",
  body: Query(
    Lambda(
      ["data"],
      Map(
        Var("data"),
        Lambda(
          "input",
          Let(
            {
              update: Update(
                Ref(Collection("FormInputVal"), Select("id", Var("input"))),
                { data: Merge(Var("input"), { id: null }) }
              )
            },
            Var("update")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
})
```

Then you can create a couple of documents:

[image: createFormInputVal]

And then update them in bulk

[image: updateMultipleInputVals]